# Inserting a large amount of data (Node.js API)

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my API in Node.js, I parse a CSV file. I get all the rows to insert them in a database. I'm using Sequelize and Mysql. And the problem is that Sequelize timeout after 1 min, and in 1min it has processed 1000 rows, while the CSV file has about 40000 rows.

In my program, I store all the data in an Object, then I have a loop that will store row by row in my database. Here is an example of what I have:

```
const csv = require('ya-csv');

const Globale = require('./models/globale.model');
const file = 'myFile.csv';
const result = [];

exports.csvToDb = (req, res) => {
  var reader = csv.createCsvFileReader(file, {columnsFromHeader: true, 'separator': ','});
  reader.addListener('data', function(data) {
    result.push(data);
  })
  reader.addListener('end', function() {
    try {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        Globale.create({
          id: result[i].id,
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Record added");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
        })
      }
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'All record uploaded' });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
  });
};
```

Do you have a way to handle this faster? And/or extend the Sequelize timeout? Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in that case you probably should use [bulk create](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#creating-in-bulk) method of sequelize, to send all data in one query.

```js
const csv = require('ya-csv');

const Globale = require('./models/globale.model');
const file = 'myFile.csv';
const result = [];

exports.csvToDb = (req, res) => {
  var reader = csv.createCsvFileReader(file, {columnsFromHeader: true, 'separator': ','});
  reader.addListener('data', function(data) {
    result.push(data);
  })
  reader.addListener('end', async function() {
    try {
      await Globale.bulkCreate(result.map(item => ({ id: item.id }))
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'All record uploaded' });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is, you are making 40.000 iterations of the `for` loop, which hammers your database with 40.000 concurrent requests.

In order to not overwhelm your DB, you could await each insertion :

```
reader.addListener('end', async function () {
    try {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            await Globale.create({ id: result[i].id })
        }
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'All record uploaded' });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
});
```

However, this is also slow because it makes 40.000 calls, albeit one by one instead of concurrently. There has to be some method of `Globale` (which I don't know) to bulk insert a great number of documents in one batch.